# Yii2 search by foreign table field and total count

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Im trying to search by a foreign table as follows:

**2 tables:**

people:

```
id
name
...
```

url:

```
id
peopleID
url
```

**People.php model**:

```
public function getUrls()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Urls::className(), ['peopleID' => 'id'])->select(['url']);
}
```

**PeopleSearch.php model:**

```
...
$query->joinWith(['urls']);
...
$query
            ->andFilterWhere(['or',
                ['like', 'name', $this->name],
                ...
                ['like', 'url', $this->name]]
        );
```

This works to search value entered in "name" field in several fields including foreign url one but in my view i enter a manual pagination by using something like:

```
$dataProvider->prepare();
if ($dataProvider->totalCount > 0) 
    echo Yii::t('app', 'Showing').": <b> ".($dataProvider->pagination->page*$dataProvider->pagination->pageSize+1)."-".($dataProvider->pagination->page*$dataProvider->pagination->pageSize+$dataProvider->count)."</b> ".Yii::t('app', 'of')." <b>".$dataProvider->totalCount."</b> ".Yii::t('app', 'items');

else echo Yii::t('app', 'No results found.');

echo LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $dataProvider->pagination])
```

And `$dataProvider->totalCount` gives me the total amount of records from joined table but not the total records from `people` one. For instance if i have 2 records in `people` table and each one has 20 urls in "url" table index.php view shows "showing 1-2 of 40 items" instead of "showing 1-2 of 2 items"

Also `LinkPager::widget` shows a wrong number of total pages

Note that `$dataProvider` is passed from the controller to the view with

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

What could I do for pagination to perform the way i want?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In People.php model my recommendation is to remove the `->select(['url'])`:

```
public function getUrls()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Urls::className(), ['peopleID' => 'id']);
}
```

This way you can still manipulate those urls if needed.

In PeopleSearch.php model:

```
...
// $query->joinWith(['urls']);
// This line is the one that makes it so you get 20 results instead of 2, because you actually get one result for each url related to the people returned by the query.

$query->with(['urls']);
// This last line makes sure the model class populates the relation using only one query.
// Two queries will end up being executed to populate both the people and url models,
// however you will get the right amount for $dataProvider->totalCount.
...
if(strlen($this->url) > 0) {
    $urlsPeopleIDs = \app\models\Url::find()
        ->select('peopleID')
        ->asArray()
        ->where(['like', 'url', $this->url])
        ->all();

    $query->andWhere(['id' => $urlsPeopleIDs]);
}
// This way you will only filter by url when you receive a url string with lenght > 0.
// If you haven't already, you will need to create a public property called 'url' in your PeopleSearch.php model and add a 'string' or 'safe' rule so you can actually load it's value from post.
```

Comment: Thank you so much @marche. Ive had to modify it a bit by getting 

->column() instead of ->all()

and ->distinct()

Thanks again!